# How to validate input fields before the submit and if the validation is ok, show message block

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, submit

[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/oj2tcLaq/3/)/*I try to make validation form and after submit
    message show success block 
    How can i validate at first and then if validation 
    is ok show success message.
    But now i can only see success block after submit
    validation

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  ('#submit').on('click', function() {
    var first_name = $('#first-name').val();
    var last_name = $('#last-name').val();
    var textarea = $('#textarea').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var company = $('#company').val();
    var submit_button = $('#submit').val();
    $(".error").remove();
    /*check first-name length*/
    if (first_name.length < 3) {
      $('#first- 
        name ').addClass('
        invalid ').after(' < span class = "error" > 
  Must be at least 3 characters < /span>');
      }
      else {
        $('#first-name').removeClass('invalid');
      }
      /*check last-name length*/
      if (last_name.length < 3) {
        $('#last- 
          name ').addClass('
          invalid ').after(' < span class = "error" 
 > Must be at least 3 characters < /span>');
        }
        else {
          $('#last-name').removeClass('invalid');
        }
        if (textarea.length < 3) {

 $('#textarea').addClass('invalid').after('<span 
            class = "error" > Must be at least 3 
 characters < /span>');
          }
          else {
            $('#textarea').removeClass('invalid');
          }
          if (email.length < 3) {
            /*check email length and check with 
  regexp*/

 $('#email').addClass('invalid').after('<span 
              class = "error" > Must be at least 3 
characters < /span>');
            }
            else {
              /*reg exp*/
              var regEx = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+
```

(.[^<>()\  []\.,;: \s @ "]+)*)|(". + "))@(([[0-9] 
    {1,3}.[0-9]  {
                  1,
                  3
                }.[0 - 9] {
                  1,
                  3
                }.[0 - 9] {
                  1,
                  3
                }]) | (([a - zA - Z\ - 0 - 9] + .) + 
     [a - zA - Z] {
              2,
            })) $ / ;
          var validEmail = regEx.test(email);
          if (!validEmail) {

```
        $('#email').addClass('invalid').after('<span 
          class = "error" > Enter a valid email < 
/span>');
        }
      }
      if (company.length < 3) {
        /*check company fieled length*/

 $('#company').addClass('invalid').after('<span 
          class = "error" > Must be at least 3 
 characters < /span>');
        }
        else {
          $('#company').removeClass('invalid');
        }
        /*call submit*/
        $('#first_form').submit(function(e) {
          $('.success-message').fadeIn();
          $('.contact-form').fadeOut();
        })
        $('#first_form').submit()
      })
    `I want to submit form and show success message, if the dorm is valid
  });
```

I cant finish the last block how to chech validation before submit

I expect that, before submitting, the form check all field according to  my valid params and if all field are valid show the message

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the form using the pattern tag.

```
<input type="text" id="regname" placeholder="name" maxlength="32" pattern="[A-Za-z\s]{1,32}" required/>
    <input type="text" id="regusername"placeholder="username" />
  <input type="password" id="regpassword" placeholder="password" required/>
  <input type="text" type="email" id="regemail"placeholder="email address" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$" required/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the js to fix the issue, let me know if it works.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit').on('click', function(e) {
    var first_name = $('#first-name').val();
    var last_name = $('#last-name').val();
    var textarea = $('#textarea').val(); 
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var company = $('#company').val(); 
    var submit_button = $('#submit').val();
    $(".error").remove();
    var invalid= false;



    if (first_name.length < 3) {
    invalid=true;
      $('#first-name').addClass('invalid').after('<span class="error">Must be at least 3 characters</span>');
    } else {
      $('#first-name').removeClass('invalid');
    }

    if (last_name.length < 3) {
    invalid=true;
      $('#last-name').addClass('invalid').after('<span class="error">Must be at least 3 characters</span>');
    } else {
      $('#last-name').removeClass('invalid');
    }

    if (textarea.length < 3) {
    invalid=true;
      $('#textarea').addClass('invalid').after('<span class="error">Must be at least 3 characters</span>');
    } else {
      $('#textarea').removeClass('invalid');
    }


    if (email.length < 3) {
    invalid=true;
      $('#email').addClass('invalid').after('<span class="error">Must be at least 3 characters</span>');
    } else {
      var regEx = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
      var validEmail = regEx.test(email);

      if (!validEmail) {
    invalid=true;
        $('#email').addClass('invalid').after('<span class="error">Enter a valid email</span>');
      } 
    }


    if (company.length < 3) {
    invalid=true;
      $('#company').addClass('invalid').after('<span class="error">Must be at least 3 characters</span>');
    } else {
      $('#company').removeClass('invalid');
    }


  /*  var isFormValid = true; */

if(!invalid){
$('#first_form').submit(function() {
     /* var isFormValid = true; */

   })   
$('.success-message').fadeIn();      
      $('.contact-form').fadeOut();
   $('#first_form').submit()
}

e.preventDefault();

 })
});
```